# jVector map displays on website but code not showing in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jvectormap

I am studying web development and as part of a project I am doing I need to add an SVG map.  I have managed to add a jVector map of New Zealand but am unable to alter in in any way because the container for the map has not displayed in HTML, it only shows in dev tools when I hover over the map.  I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

I have been trying to find an answer online but haven't found the same issue anywhere and no one on my course seems to know either.  I followed videos on you tube but did it slightly different because in the videos they put everything on the HTML page including any JS or JQuery and on my course they have said these should be kept in a separate file, so I wonder if this is causing the problem.  I did try however putting it directly into the HTML but got the same result.

[This shows API info displaying in Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Lid.png)
[Shows files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVadB.png)

```
<!--JVECTOR SCRIPT TOP OF PAGE-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jsvector/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <script src="assets/jsvector/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jsvector/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jsvector/jquery-jvectormap-nz-mill.js"></script>
```

```
<!--START OF JVECTOR MAP DIV EMPTY-->
               <div id="map">
                </div> 

            <!--END OF JVECTOR MAP-->
```

```
//SCRIPT KEPT IN SPEARATE FILE FROM HTML BUT REFERENCING #MAP IN HTML
$(function(){
      $('#map').vectorMap({map: 'nz_mill'});
    });
```

I expected to see all of the map info from the API show under the #map div in HTML like it had done on the demo videos I watched.  It has obviously connected OK but I have no way to adjust anything on it.